# Confusion with x86_64 Windows calling convention

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

The platform is x86_64 Windows 7.

Here is the C source code:

```
#include<windows.h>
int main(void){
    asm("int3");
    CreateWindowEx(0,NULL,NULL,0,5,6,7,8,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    return(0);
}
```

Which compiles to the following assembly:

```
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
sub rsp,60h
int3
mov qword[rsp+58h],0
mov qword[rsp+50h],0
mov qword[rsp+48h],0
mov qword[rsp+40h],0
mov qword[rsp+38h],8
mov qword[rsp+30h],7
mov qword[rsp+28h],6
mov qword[rsp+20h],5
mov r9d,0
mov r8d,0
mov edx,0
mov ecx,0
call CreateWindowEx
mov eax,0
add rsp,60h
pop rbp
ret
```

And conceptually this is what I have for the stack at various points of execution (the addresses are arbitrary):

```
90 -rsp-

90 old rbp
88 -rsp-

90 old rbp
88 -rsp- -rbp-

90 old rbp
88 -rbp- (never used?)
80 (rsp+58h)
78 (rsp+50h)
70 (rsp+48h)
68 (rsp+40h)
60 (rsp+38h)
58 (rsp+30h)
50 (rsp+28h)
48 (rsp+20h)
40 (shadow)
38 (shadow)
30 (shadow)
28 -rsp- (shadow) (will contain call instruction's return pointer...)
```

As you can see there are problems with the stack according to the compiled output of the C program. First off there's 8 bytes that never get used, and 8 bytes of the shadow space will be overwritten by the call instruction for the return pointer. It seems that everything is shifted down 8 bytes more than it should be, because it would be fine if it was shifted 8 bytes up. However the API calls work just as expected, is this just an overlook of Microsoft's implementation of the calling convention?

Comment: The stack list that you provided is actually the local variables of `CreateWindowEx`, not the function's parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When something is pushed on to the stack, the new item doesn't go where `rsp` is pointing when the instruction starts - `rsp` is decremented before storing the new item (ie., the stack location that `rsp` points to is in use).

So, if `rsp ==0x90` when starting that function, the old `rbp` will be at address `0x88` (and `rbp` will be made to point to that address).

Then when `rsp == 0x28` and the `call` instruction is executed, the return address will be placed in address `0x20`, not `0x28`.